# faces falling below the sculpted face when re-topologizing

Tags: modeling, workflow, sculpting, topology

I have sculpted a human head in Blender, and now I am doing re-topology. This is for the first time I am doing, and I am kind of new to Blender, and in this 3D field for that matter.

See the picture below

[image]

The portion I marked with blue marker, it shows that the retopologized grids are there but it falls below the sculpted face, though I am using "snap to grid" and "srinkwrap" modifier and I suppose it is due to less geometry.

If I give more geometry, the retopology in that portion looks messy and increases polygons.

My question is if I bake a normal map will those raised portions of my sculpt be captured in the baked image and then be transformed to my low poly retopology model?

If not, how to achieve that?

Comment: Seems like you don't have enough geometry to follow all of the contours of the original mesh.

Comment: @cegaton that is true. But you see, if I add geometry using ctrl + r it would make it messy. What is the solution?

Comment: Try to create geometry that corresponds with the highest parts of the mesh.

Comment: @cegaton yes that is correct. But you see my problem is, especially in case of that raised portion which is not on the boundary. If we try to add geometry it will disturb the other parts of the retopology. Can u show how to come up with the solution?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=ear+topology&safe=off&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=UeRvbZuEJU-BQM%253A%252CkdBS9DjndKCOYM%252C_&usg=__LFL5iNyCODMneAPNDPw5eq0ECSc%3D&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjL9ZnuuqnYAhUNwGMKHYU4AZAQ9QEIKzAA#imgrc=UeRvbZuEJU-BQM:

Comment: @cegaton :'( now that's is going to be painful lot of work :'(

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the faces being below the surface is that the vertices and edges that make up the faces in those regions are not on the highest points of your mesh. When the faces are made, they connect in a straight line, which in this case goes through a portion of your mesh. The two ways to deal with this are to add more vertices so that the faces can follow the contour of your mesh better, or reposition your vertices so that the detail is better preserved. If your end goal is baking normals, you will want both objects to be as close as possible. Here are a few tips to make your retopology process a bit easier:

1) Instead of starting at one point and working your way around the ear, start by identifying where you want your edge loops to be, and what details you want to highlight.

2) To do this, I've always found it easiest to use snapping set to face, and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> click to extrude a single vertex and create your edge loops. If you enable automatic snapping (the little magnet icon) each new vertex will snap to the surface where you click.

3) Place your edge loops at the highest and lowest points possible. If there is a ridge or bump, place the loop so it is on the highest point. Do the same for any valleys or indents.

4) Keep in mind that you will have to connect all of these loops together eventually, so plan where each vertex will connect to the others.

5) Finally, begin connecting your edge loops to each other. You won't have enough edge loops to simply fill single faces between edges, so add more vertices where necessary. If you use some topology guides and plan your topology carefully, it shouldn't be to difficult to add in extra detail where you need it.